# Storing Path in a Variable and Reading it in another py file?

Tags: python

Quick question:
I have a panel.py file, a operator.py file, and a `__init__` that puts it all together.

My panel has a class that uses a `bpy.types.PropertyGroup` to store a PropertyString into a variable called `file_path`. It also has a class that uses `bpy.types.Panel` to create the PropertyString like this:

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    col = layout.column()

    tools = context.scene.worth_group_tools
    selected_path = col.prop(tools, "file_path")
```

My question is, how do I access this variable on my operator.py page? I've tried:

```
from . Tools_panel import PT_Panel
def execute(self, context):
   print(PT_Panel.draw.selected_path)
   return {'FINISHED'}
```

But that doesn't work.  Any suggestions?  My code works fine until I try to print with `PT_Panel.draw.selected_path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `file_path` in the operator, just like you did in the panel, by using the `context`. Through it you get a reference to the same instance of the `PropertyGroup` that stores your settings.

`context.scene.worth_group_tools.file_path` will give you the `StringProperty`.

You cannot access a local variable that only exists in the function scope from outside the object.

Comment: I would suggest you learn more about the concept of the call stack, scoping, pointers/references, classes and objects. It's quite a bit to learn, but it will make it so much clearer why your approach doesn't work. The following links explain some of the concepts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981391/how-exactly-does-the-callstack-work https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Thanks again rjg.